# Does having children create very strong attachment (Moh)? Is this hindrance to Moksha?

Tags: moksha, children, non-attachment

It is commonly seen that most men are very strongly attached to their offsprings

Is this the reason why most Hindu seers don't get married.
As they want Moksha and a strong attachment with one's offspring can be roadblock to get Moksha ?

Is there such thing written in scriptures ?

Comment: This is a very weird question. It is like having a brother is a hindrance to moksha? (It depends!). There's no way having more family members creates a strong attachment than having fewer family members, be it anything - kids, brothers, or whatever. Moskha as a result is dependent on you only and not your surroundings. People renouncing family are at very high risk of mistaking, leading themselves into hell. This is ignorance. Family can be a distraction, just like anything else, but such a conclusion is absurd.

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha But most Hindu seers remain unmarried. Even Shankaracharya who are known to be orthodox and follow scriptures quite literally (for which they are sometimes criticized also) remain unmarried.
There must be some huge advantage in not getting married. Otherwise why would most of them remain unmarried ?

Comment: It is just common sense Adi Shankaracharya was unmarried NOT because of personal reasons, but just because he was sent to travel all over India and spread the ideals of Advaita Vedanta and Smarta tradition. He cannot do well with a family and kids. I already said *renouncing* family is definitely not a good idea, even spiritually.

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha Even most present shankaracharya are also unmarried. Plus most Hindu seers of other sects are also not married. 
[I am using the example of Shankaracharya not b/c they have some kind of authority as only scriptures have authority in hinduism but b/c shankaracharyas are known to be follow scriptures quite literally.]

Comment: It is their problem. The goal of shastras is not to dictate marriage to you. They just have rules to follow for a certain spiritual goal. If you don't want to marry if a certain shastra says to you, then it is your own personal choice. If you want to focus on the end goal, then you don't need to worry about the boat taking you - when you already know how to swim.